# Webpack Dev Server proxy no redirecciona a mi api backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, apache, webpack

Estoy intentando redireccionar las rutas "http://localhost:3000/api/*" a "http://example.com/api/*" donde se ejecuta un servidor apache.

Esta es mi configuracion de webpack dev server:

```
devServer: {
    publicPath: '/build/',
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://gestios.loc/api'
        }
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Cuando intento acceder a  http://localhost:3000/api/calltek/apps?permalink=empresas recibo un 404.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/calltek/apps?permalink=empresas
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
date: Fri, 05 May 2017 18:13:42 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28
vary: accept-language,accept-charset
accept-ranges: bytes
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-type: text/html
content-language: es
```

Comment: No me di cuenta que estaba posteando en el sitio español. Disculpas.

Comment: Solucionado siguiendo este hilo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662065/webpack-dev-server-proxy-dosent-work